# Is there any way to get all users from Active Directory using Kerberos?

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, kerberos

I have an asp.net core application and authentication scheme using Kerberos with a keytab file on Linux.
I want to synchronize user list from Active Directory with users in my database to have relevant values of first and last names and no one could get an access if its credentials were deleted from AD.
Is there any way to do it via keytab file or kerberos generally?

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you doing Kerberos with ASP.NET Core on Linux? What library are you using?

In any case you have options:

1. Use the details provided in the Kerberos ticket itself. The ticket contains the username plus optionally the PAC which contains some information like user display name (not first and last) plus group information. See [the format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-pac/69e86ccc-85e3-41b9-b514-7d969cd0ed73) for specifics.
2. With the Kerberos credential you have in the keytab, request an LDAP ticket from the KDC and query Active Directory for those details.

Since option 1 doesn't really give you everything you need, it sounds like option 2 is going to be more effective.

Comment: I'm using Kerberos.NET, it allows to validate kerberos ticket without too much magic. And it's right that kerberos does not give us first and last name, so it won't work. Can you give a little more information regarding ldap ticket? How can I get it?

Comment: `var c = new KerberosClient(); await c.Authenticate(new KeytabCredential(...)); var ticket = c.GetServiceTicket("ldap/yourdc");` Then you need an LDAP library that can use the ticket to query AD.